# Why ubuntu rebooting again and again after xen installation?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, xen

I have installed ubuntu 14.04.it booted normally. but when I installed xen the computer is stuck in reboot loop (its rebooting again and again) showing the message "kernel panic - not syncing attempted to kill init exit code=0x0000009".I searched in internet and found the below solution

1. memory test -passed
2. Using LVM
3. booting in legacy mode
4. boot repair
5. enabling virtualization in BIOS
6. using different version of ubuntu

   Unfortunately nothing worked :( can anyone pleassssse help me? so that I get XEN working.